# Inhomogouse Differential Problem Help

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

An inhomogenous differential equation system is given as,

$$\left( \begin{matrix} \overset { . }{ x_{ 1 } }  \\ \overset { . }{ x_{ 2 } }  \end{matrix} \right) =\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 3 \\ -3 & -1 \end{pmatrix}\left( \begin{matrix} x_{ 1 } \\ x_{ 2 } \end{matrix} \right) +\left( \begin{matrix} 1 \\ 3 \end{matrix} \right)  $$

**Questions**

i) Determine the complete complex solution to the corresponding homogeneous system.

(ii) Determine the complete real solution to the corresponding homogeneous system.

(iii) Determine the complete real solution to the given inhomogeneous system.

**Approach**
I have solve the first two parts,

i) For the first part,
$$x(t)=c_{ 1 }{ e }^{ (-1+3i) }\left( \begin{matrix} 1 \\ i \end{matrix} \right) +c_{ 2 }{ e }^{ (-1-3i) }\left( \begin{matrix} 1 \\ -i \end{matrix} \right)$$

ii) For the second part, I got the following,
$$x(t)=c_{ 1 }{ e }^{ (-1t) }\left( \begin{matrix} cos(3t) \\ -sin(3t) \end{matrix} \right) +c_{ 2 }{ e }^{ (-1t) }\left( \begin{matrix} sin(3t) \\ cos(3t) \end{matrix} \right) $$

But I am stuck at the last part. I dont understand how to find the complete real solution for the nonhomogenous equation.

Any help would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Since you know the matrix exponential, you can simply do $\displaystyle x(t) = e^{A t}\left( x_0 + \int_{t_0}^t e^{-A s}f(s)~ds\right)$.

Comment: @Moo I tried using that equation but I do not completely understand the variables. In the integral, what are the limits? How do i find them? and what is $x_0$.

Comment: Let's say you are given $x(0)$, then $t_0 = 0$ and the upper limit is just $t$. $f(s) = (1, 3)$ (a column vector). of course, $f(s)$ could have also been a function of time.

Comment: Thank You very much. I was finally able to solve the question.

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods for this.  Variation of parameters is one way, and it's basically a formula you just plug in for.  The other is undetermined coefficients.  You assume an solution of a certain form and then plug it in to the system and see what the constants have to be.  In this case, assume your solution is $\left( \begin{matrix} x_{ 1 } \\ x_{ 2 } \end{matrix} \right)=\left( \begin{matrix} A \\ B \end{matrix} \right)$ where $A$ and $B$ are constants.  Then

$$\left( \begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{matrix} \right) = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 3 \\ -3 & -1 \end{pmatrix} \left( \begin{matrix} A \\ B \end{matrix} \right)+\left( \begin{matrix} 1 \\ 3 \end{matrix} \right)$$
From which you deduce that $A=2/5$ and $B=-1/5$.  The final solution is your answer from part 2 added to the particular solution $\left( \begin{matrix} 2/5 \\ -1/5 \end{matrix} \right).$